# How to set Bootstrap theme for django-endless-pagination?

Tags: django, twitter-bootstrap, pagination

I'm new to Django and front-end development. I would like to build some Django app with pagination, using the Bootstrap theme. I found `django-endless-pagination` is quite useful for pagination. To have the Bootstrap theme, I tried [`django-endless-pagination-bootstrap-theme`](https://github.com/mozillazg/django-endless-pagination-bootstrap-theme).

I have my `views.py` just returned a list of entries to be shown in `display.html` which is coded as:

```
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css">

{% load endless %}

{% paginate entries %}

{% for entry in entries %}
    <p>{{ entry.value }}</p>
{% endfor %}

<div class="pagination">
{% show_pages %}
</div>
```

However, the pagination style I have (shown in Fig. 1) is quite different from that shown in the website of [`django-endless-pagination-bootstrap-theme`](https://github.com/mozillazg/django-endless-pagination-bootstrap-theme) (copied as in Fig. 2).

**Fig. 1**

[image]

**Fig. 2**

[image]

May I know what the problems are in my example?

Thank you.

Comment: the code on github is for bootstrap2, and you are using bootstrap3

Comment: @Cheng, thanks for the comment. In this case, may I know if there is some work around for bootstrap3?

Comment: I don't think you need to use the code from github. Just follow boostrap3's guideline and style the elements yourself would be sufficient.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to include in your html file (before the `body` closing tag) the `.js` files too. For ex:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

**UPDATE**

Maybe, instead of

```
<div class="pagination">
{% show_pages %}
</div>
```

you could so something like this using bootstrap 3.3.4

```
{% get_pages %}
<ul class="pagination">
{% for page in pages %}
    <li><a href="{{ page.url }}">{{ page.number }}</a></li>
{% endfor %}
</ul>
```

Comment: I added the two lines in the html file. But the style is still the same.

Comment: The code on github is two years old so it doesn't work for bootstrap 3.3.4. But, as @Cheng said, you could style your pagination using bootstrap.

Comment: I made a full example with first, previous, next, and last pages in case someone still finds it useful. https://djangosnippets.org/snippets/10546/

Comment: @se210 thank you for this link, but it seems to me that `{% if page == None %}` condition never triggered. Next your code return all pages without ... symbols. For example in my case I see 200 pages. How to fix it?

Answer (score 4):

For bootstrap 3 with django-el-pagination using ajax, replace {% show pages %} with the following:

```
{% get_pages %}
    <ul class="pagination">
        {% for page in pages %}
            <li>
                <a href="{{ page.path }}" rel="page" class="endless_page_link">{{ page.number }}</a>
            </li>
        {% endfor %}
   </ul>
```

Comment: Doesn't work for me, this dumps ALL the page numbers on the page.